# How do I get the id of record in foreign key table using another column in that table in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. Using Entity Framework 6, I am working on a project to store employee skills in a database. The user can enter a new skill into a list of skills. I would like to keep track of who added the new skill. I have a table of all of the employees.

These are the models for the two tables.

```
 public partial class Skill
 {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Skill { get; set; }
   [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
   public int LastActionUserID { get; set; }

   public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class Employee
 {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeLAN { get; set; }
   public int LastActionUserID { get; set; }

   public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }//References itself for LastActionUserID
   public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills{ get; set; } //Omitted in initial question
 }
```

There is a 1 to Many mapping of Employee to Skill. I can get the current user's EmployeeLAN but how do I get the id of that Employee record to put into the Skill table automatically when then new skill is created? Must I convert the table to an enumerable object and use SingleOrDefault or LINQ? Or is there an easier way using EF6? Also, setting this automatically when a new skill is created would be done in the controller, correct?

Comment: In your Employee class this should be Skill. `public virtual List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }`

Comment: What is LAN? Last Action something??

Comment: LAN is the user's network id.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track and you should continue to use EF6.

The Employee class should have a Skills list. That way you can call myEmployee.Skills and have a list of all the skills available.

```
public partial class Employee
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeLAN { get; set; }
   public int LastActionUserID { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills{ get; set; }
}
```

> Also, setting this automatically when a new skill is created would be done in the controller, correct?

You'll need to add to the Skills list, call AddOrUpdate() to mark this as changed, then SaveChanges() to persist it to the database.

I recommend learning more from the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and Julie Learman's 
[Entity Framework videos on Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/entity-framework-6-getting-started)

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. When I am adding a new skill using AddOrUpdate, how would I populate the LastActionUserID field since all I have is the LAN Id and not the id of that record?